# Spring JPA findByDomainClass generates wrong where clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I encountered a problem when I using Spring JPA. I googled and researched for half day but no result. Let me show you my code. I have written an entity that references another domain class with foreign key in database but the join column of the entity is not the primary key 'id'. The two entities is as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    ... getters and setters ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_timebank")
public class TimebankEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private UserEntity user;
    ... getters and setters ...
}
```

I use the spring JPA CrudRepository to do the custom query:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    public UserEntity findByUsername(String username);
}

@Repository
public interface TimebankRepository extends CrudRepository<TimebankEntity, Long> {
    public TimebankEntity findByUser(UserEntity user);
}
```

That's very simple. However when I do my business logic in the service,something goes wrong.

```
@Service
public class TimebankService {
    @Autowired
    TimebankRepository timebankRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    public TimebankDto getTimebank(String username) {
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        TimebankEntity timebankEntity = timebankRepository
                .findByUser(userEntity);
        return new TimebankDto(timebankEntity.getUser().getUsername(),
                timebankEntity.getLeaveType().getCode(),
                timebankEntity.getTotalHours(),
                timebankEntity.getAvailableHours());
    }
}
```

I run the code above with username 'Tom' and I can get the right userEntity that exists in my database. But the findByUser(userEntity) return null result. The sql and message generated by hibernate are the following output:

```
Hibernate: select userentity0_.id as id1_2_, userentity0_.introduction as introduc2_2_, userentity0_.password as password3_2_, userentity0_.username as username4_2_ from tb_user userentity0_ where userentity0_.username=?
Hibernate: select timebanken0_.id as id1_1_, timebanken0_.available_hours as availabl2_1_, timebanken0_.leave_type as leave_ty4_1_, timebanken0_.total_hours as total_ho3_1_, timebanken0_.username as username5_1_ from tb_timebank timebanken0_ left outer join tb_user userentity1_ on timebanken0_.username=userentity1_.id where userentity1_.id=?
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:SQL Warning Code: 1292, SQLState: 22007
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Tom'
```

It seems that the 'Tom' was assigned to the field 'id' so it returns a null result, but why could this happen? what's wrong with my code? I checked the spring jpa reference but I didn't find an answer. Please give me some advice and thanks advance!

Comment: Just curious: Why do you @JoinColumn by a non-Id field? Wouldn't it be much more useful to join by id?

Comment: The index key in the database is a foreign key `tb_timebank(username) references tb_user(username)`, primary key of `tb_user` and `tb_timebank` are both an `id` and the two id doesn't have foreign key constraint.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Thanks for your quick response. There're 2 reasons. Firstly I have set a foreign key in database. Secondly I can get the username directly from the tb_timebank. As you said I replace the @JoinColumn annotation with `@JoinColumn(insertable=false,updatable=false,referencedColumnName = "id")` and then I get another message: ` Unknown column 'timebanken0_.user_id' in 'field list'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're looking at the wrong place. You have a JPA mapping problem here, and your JPA implementation is Hibernate. So you should look for the problem in the JPA/Hibernate documentation, not in the Spring documentation.

You've told JPA/Hibernate that there was an association between TimebankEntity and UserEntity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
private UserEntity user;
```

So that means that there is a column `username`, in the table `tb_timebank`, that is used to reference a row of the `tb_user` table. But you don't say, anywhere, which column of the `tb_user` table this column references.

What is the most natural way to uniquely reference a row of another table? The primary key of course. So, of course, if you don't specify anything, that's what JPA will use. How to change that?

Let's read the [API documentation of JoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName%28%29):

> referencedColumnName
>
> public abstract java.lang.String referencedColumnName
>
> (Optional) The name of the column referenced by this foreign key column.
>
> [...]
>
> Default (only applies if single join column is being used): The same name as the primary key column of the referenced table.

So, by default, the referenced column name is the name of the column of the primary key of the referencedtable, i.e. `tb_user.id`.

To reference another column, you need to specify a value for this attribute:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
```

That said, you'd better use the default value: this will be more efficient, won't cause problems if two users have the same name, and won't force you to update `tb_timebank`when the user changes his name.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. I try replacing the @JoinColumn you gave above and now I get the generated sql: `Hibernate: select timebanken0_.id as id1_1_, timebanken0_.available_hours as availabl2_1_, timebanken0_.leave_type as leave_ty4_1_, timebanken0_.total_hours as total_ho3_1_, timebanken0_.username as username5_1_ from tb_timebank timebanken0_ left outer join tb_user userentity1_ on timebanken0_.username=userentity1_.username where userentity1_.id is null`. On the other hand, I actually have tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: You get this SQL from what? Which repository method did you call, and with which argument?

Comment: @Nizet: I just replace my @JoinColumn with `@JoinColumn(name="username",referencedColumnName = "username")` and run the `findByUser(userEntity)` in above service class and get that sql from the console with the property 'spring.jpa.show-sql=true'.

Comment: And I guess that you called that method with a userEntity instance with a null ID. So, the generated query is absolutely correct. You asked for the TimeBanks linked to a User identified by the ID null, and that's what the query does. Passing an entity to a query is equivalent to searching by its ID. JPA queries are not "queries by example". To search by user name, you would need a findByUserUsername(String userName) method. Or better, any method annotated with `@Query("select tb from Timebank tb where tb.user.username = :userName")`

Comment: @Nizet: Firstly, I debug and found that the `user` argument passed in the `findByUser()` method has a non-null id. The `findByUsername()` works fine. The problem is at the `findByUser()` method. Then I tried your `@Query` annotation and it get the normal result. I'm confused. Is the usage of `findByUser()` in my code wrong?